# Angular2: Add host dynamically

Tags: angular

Version: "angular2": "2.0.0-beta.6"

I would like to add a new `host` dynamically on a `@directive`.

Example:

```
@Directive({
    selector: '[test]',
    host: {
        '(mousedown)': '_onmousedown($event)'
    }
})
export class TestDirective {

    _onmousedown(e){
        // Here add a new host dynamically. For example, add a MouseMove listener on the element.
    }
```

}

**[1]** Is it possible to do such things without manipulating the DOM directly ?

**[2]** Also, is it possible to stop listening for `mousedown` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't add/remove host bindings dynamically.

For this inject `ElementRef` and `Renderer` and add/remove it imperatively.

Comment: What the difference between `ElementRef.nativeElement.addEventListener()` and `Renderer.listen()` ? `Renderer` isn't documented yet, do you have some example links ?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure but I think the former isn't webworker/server safe while the later is (doesn't call anything on `nativeElement` directly).